# Probability in infinitary logic

Tags: probability, infinity

Let X be a random variable taking the value 0.2 with probability 0.2, 0.4 with probability 0.4 and 0.8 with probability 0.2 and 1.0 with probability 0.2.

Using [Infinitary logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic) I can ask the probability:

$$P(X = P(X = P(X = \ldots)))$$

How is is this value computed?

Comment: I don't see how you can express anything close to anything looking like the thing you wrote with infinitary logic. Maybe you just want to study the set $\{x \in [0;1] / P(X=x) = x\}$ ?

Comment: If you think this expression belongs to the framework of infinitary logic, you should explain why. Otherwise one could get the feeling that, to you, *infinitary logic* is a shorthand for *everything seemingly paradoxical and with $\cdots$ in it*.